# KTor or Spark? Which is production ready for Kotlin web services?

Tags: java, rest, kotlin

I am writing an enterprise web service application using Kotlin. I am now using KTor since it is async and high performant But as you may know, Ktor is somewhat young, and the feature 'coroutine' is experimental in Kotlin! Is it wise to use Ktor anyway?

Comment: are you read the kotlin reference? async? high performant? maybe you need to see https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/faq.html

Comment: In its current wording your question is opinion based, which it should not be according to the rules of SO. Please rephrase your question if you don't want it to be closed.

Comment: @holi-java I suely know Kotlin is compiled into JVM I meant async and NIO (in Ktor) makes my code faster than using e.g. Spark (Maybe!) and I know I can write the same code in pure Java using netty! Please keep in mind people know what they ask !

Comment: first, I never down or close your question. but I didn't understand you why did you say kotlin is async & high performance?

Comment: @holi-java I did not say Kotlin is so! I told Ktor is since Ktor has merged Kotlin coroutine feature with Java's great NIO into a good http mirco-framework.

Comment: @Kamyar I'm sorry I didn't see it clearly since I saw it at last night.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Despite the `experimental` status, Kotlin coroutines are fully released and guarantied to work far in the future.

The `experimental` flag is mostly for library writers. Since you are doing an application, there will be no problem in using coroutines even after the final version is released. Your code will continue to work with the `kotlinx.coroutines.experimental` library, that's it.

As for the Ktor, then I can say that what it does it does well. Since it is a relatively light framework, I would not expect any bugs from it. So, if you like its API, there is no reason not to use it. After all, the integration with Kotlin is far beyond that of Spark.